# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing this clock project where I need to apply transform property to the hour hand for the rotation but I'm having this error. I've checked my HTML and all the selectors are correct.

```
const hour = document.querySelector('.hour');
const minute = document.querySelector('.minute');
const second = document.querySelector('.second');

function time(){
  const date = new Date();
  const sec = date.getSeconds();
  const secDegree = ((sec/60) * 360) + 90;
  second.style.transform = `rotate(${secDegree}deg)`;

  const min = date.getMinutes();
  const minDegree = ((min/60) * 360) + 90;
  minute.style.transform = `rotate(${minDegree}deg)`;

  const hour = date.getHours();
  const hourDegree = ((min/12) * 360) + 90;
  hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegree}deg)`;
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

//html

```
    <div class="clockFace">
        <div class="hand minute"></div>
        <div class="hand hour"></div>
        <div class="hand second"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You've defined a new variable `hour` (`const hour = date.getHours();`) inside the `time` function.

Comment: yes, thank you I got it

Comment: @buazz You also divided the minute by 12 not the hour in your `hourDegree` variable assignment. Check my answer for the corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
const hour = document.querySelector('.hour');
const minute = document.querySelector('.minute');
const second = document.querySelector('.second');

function time(){
  const date = new Date();
  const sec = date.getSeconds();
  const secDegree = ((sec/60) * 360) + 90;
  second.style.transform = `rotate(${secDegree}deg)`;
  second.innerText = secDegree;

  const min = date.getMinutes();
  const minDegree = ((min/60) * 360) + 90;
  minute.style.transform = `rotate(${minDegree}deg)`;
  minute.innerText = minDegree ;

  const hr = date.getHours();
  const hourDegree = ((min/12) * 360) + 90;
  hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegree}deg)`;
  hour.innerText = hr;
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

```css
    .hour {
      height: 6px;
      background: red;
    }
    .minute {
      height: 4px; 
      background: green;
    }
    .second {
      height: 2px;
      background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 50px;" class="clockFace">
        <div class="hand minute"></div>
        <div class="hand hour"></div>
        <div class="hand second"></div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name `hour` inside your `time()` function to the shorthand version `hr` and in your `hourdegree` variable assignment, change `(min/12)` to `(hr/12)`.

```
function time(){

  /* other code */

  const hr= date.getHours();
  const hourDegree = ((hr/12) * 360) + 90;
  hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegree}deg)`;
}
```